# creating a template in umbraco where is the HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, umbraco, page-title

Okay so i'm new to Umbraco, And i've created a template, and all i can see in the editor is this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/umbraco/masterpages/default.master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

But I'm not able to see the  and  tag, so how do i define which CSS file i use, or how do i set the pagetitle?

I've tried to set the tags manually but that dosen't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also new to Umbraco and found this very confusing as the Default masterpage is actually blank.  This means you need to create the full template you want to use within your main content placeholder `ContentPlaceHolderDefault` like so:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9 ie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title><umbraco:item runat="server" field="pageName" /> - <umbraco:item runat="server" field="siteName" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">


</form>
</body>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: and can i then add additional contentplaceholders inside them?

Comment: yes - you can then use this as you would use a normal masterpage template

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net there is a `contentplaceholder`
`ContentPlaceHolderID` is set to `head` means it's a head section of you page.

Your can set anything it woks as a head of normal html page.

```
   <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
          <script src="Scripts/name.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </asp:Content>
```

Here you can put your files

Comment: can i also set my pagetitle in there?